# How to calculate an int value and an float64 value in Golang?

Tags: go, type-conversion

On the following code I could not understand why the declaration `a = int(b)` didn't convert the value of **b** to *int*. Also, what is the point in doing so if we can achieve the same result omitting this line entirely anyways?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a, b := 10, 5.5
    a = int(b)
    fmt.Println(float64(a) + b)
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the purpose of this code? with the purpose, code can be cleaned.

Comment: Think of `int()` as a function which takes in a float and returns an int. Why do you expect it to internally change the value/type of `b`?

Comment: a = int(b) would resign a with the value of 5, hope this link helps :https://golangdocs.com/type-casting-in-golang

Answer (score 1):

`a, b := 10, 5.5`
In this line, value `10` is assigned to the `a` with default type `int` and value `5.5` is assigned to the `b` with default type `float64`. [tour here](https://tour.golang.org/basics/10)

then `a = int(b)` this line get integer value of `b`, that is `5` and assigned to `a`. If you don't need `a`'s previous value then those two line can be write as follow and get same result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    b := 5.5
    a := int(b)
    fmt.Println(float64(a) + b) //Output: 10.5
}
```

`fmt.Println(float64(a) + b)` you can not do operations with different types. that's why you need to convert `a` to `float64` and do the operation. result also a `float64` if you assigned it to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
a=int(b)
```

`a` becomes 5. So:

```
float64(a)+b
```

becomes 10.5, because `a=5` and `b=5.5`

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a, b := 10, 5.5
    a = int(b)
    fmt.Println(float64(a) + b, a)
}
```

Outputs

```
10.5 5
```

It seems like it is converting b to int -> 5 -> a = a+b = 5 + 5.5 = 10.5

Here b is typecasted to int and putting that value in a.

If you need to change the value of b you should do `b = int(b)`.

Comment: b = int(b) would result in error as follows :cannot use int(b) (type int) as type float64 in assignment